# The abelian group of homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, dynamical-systems

Let $G$ be a subgroup of the group of homeomorphisms on the circle, and we suppose $G$ is abelian, if every element of $G$ has a fixed point on the circle, does it imply that $G$ has a common fixed point?

Comment: Any element, or every element? Because the identity element has a fixed point, so if it's really "any" then the question simplifies a bit.

Comment: @EricStucky it is every element.

Comment: I have fixed the question text, as per the clarification of OP.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $G$ must have a common fixed point.

Let me give the proof first under the assumption that $G$ preserves orientation.

First a special case: assume $G$ is generated by two elements $f,g$. Arguing by contradiction, suppose $Fix(f) \cap Fix(g) = \emptyset$. Then there exists a component $J$ of $S^1 - Fix(f)$ which contains at least one element of $Fix(g)$. The subset $J$ is homeomorphic to the real line, and $f$ restricts to an orientation preserving, fixed point free homeomorphism of $J$, and so there is a homeomorphism $J \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ that conjugates $f \, | \, J$ to the translation map $x \mapsto x+1$. On the other hand, since $f$ and $g$ commute, $f$ must take the set $J \cap Fix(g)$ to itself. This is impossible because $J \cap Fix(g)$ is a compact subset of $J$ and the translation map $x \mapsto x+1$ does not preserve any compact subset.

One can use transfinite induction on a well-ordered generating set to get the general case that $G$ preserves orientation: the above argument can be used for the finite induction step; and for the limiting induction step one can use that the intersection of compact nested sets is nonempty.

I also had a proof for the case that $G$ has an orientation reversing element, but that proof had an error and I have removed it. I'll try to fix that up later.

Comment: I donnot understand why "there is a homeomorphism that conjugates $f$ to $x\mapsto x+1$", could you explain it?

Comment: @Petter: Take any point $x_0 \in J$. Define $x_i = f^i(x_0)$. Since $f$ has no fixed points on $J$, the points $…,x_{-1},x_0,x_1,…$ must occur in order on $J$, and the limits of $x_i$ as $i \to \pm\infty$ must be the two endpoints of $J$. These points subdivide $J$ into closed intervals $[x_k,x_{k+1}]$. Now pick any orientation preserving homeomorphism $h : [x_0,x_1] \to [0,1]$. This extends to a homeomorphism $J \to \mathbb{R}$ taking $[x_k,x_{k+1}]$ to $[k,k+1]$, which takes $x \in [x_k,x_{k+1}]$ to $h(f^{-k}(x))+k$.